# Why can't I resolve AW.Utility ReturnCodes and InstanceExceptions?

Tags: c#, sdk, wrapper, activeworlds

Sorry the title is kind of confusing, but it is the best way I could explain it without taking up too much space. And please excuse my formatting, I'm pretty new to stackoverflow. Here is the problem, I have some sample code that I found for a C# wrapper for a C++ SDK. The program that uses the SDK is called ActiveWorlds. The code is here:

```
using System;
using AW;
namespace GreeterBotCSharp
{
    class GreeterBot
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Main entry point into the GreeterBot program.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="args">Command line arguments.</param>
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Prompt the user for their citizen number.
            Console.Write("Enter citizen number: ");
            int citizenNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            //Prompt the user for their privilege password.
            Console.Write("Enter privilege password: ");
            string privilegePassword = Console.ReadLine();

            //Prompt the user for a world to enter.
            Console.Write("Enter a world name: ");
            string world = Console.ReadLine();

            //Create a new copy of the GreeterBot and run it.
            GreeterBot bot = new GreeterBot();
            bot.Run(citizenNumber, privilegePassword, world);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Runs a new GreeterBot with the specified owner and privilege password.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="owner">The citizen number of the person who owns the bot.</param>
        /// <param name="password">The privilege password of the person who owns the bot.</param>
        /// <param name="world">The name of the world to greet in.</param>
        private void Run(int owner, string password, string world)
        {
            try
            {
                //Create a new instance and set events
                Instance greeterBot = new Instance();
                greeterBot.EventAvatarAdd += new Instance.Event(greeterBot_EventAvatarAdd);

                //Log the instance into the ActiveWorlds universe
                try
                {
                    greeterBot.SetInt(Attributes.LoginOwner, owner);
                    greeterBot.SetString(Attributes.LoginPrivilegePassword, password);
                    greeterBot.SetString(Attributes.LoginName, "GreeterBot");
                    greeterBot.Login();
                }
                catch (InstanceException ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Failed to login (Reason: {0}).", Utility.ReturnCodes[ex.ErrorCode]);
                    return; //Application failed, quit.
                }

                //Enter a world and attempt to go to ground zero.
                try
                {
                    greeterBot.Enter(world);
                    greeterBot.StateChange();
                }
                catch (InstanceException ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Failed to enter world at ground zero (Reason: {0}).", Utility.ReturnCodes[ex.ErrorCode]);
                    return; //Application failed, quit.
                }

                //Event dispatch loop.  This is important, without it events would not be dispatched appropriately.
                while (Utility.Wait(-1) == 0) ;

            }
            catch (InstanceException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unexpected Error (Reason: {0}).", Utility.ReturnCodes[ex.ErrorCode]);
                return; //Application failed, quit.
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Event handler for avatars entering the proximity of the bot.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The instance that received the event.  This is extremely important,
        /// especially if instances share common event handlers.  We use it here to control the instance.</param>
        void greeterBot_EventAvatarAdd(Instance sender)
        {
            try
            {
                //Store the session and name of the avatar, and the name of the world.
                int userSession = sender.GetInt(Attributes.AvatarSession);
                string userName = sender.GetString(Attributes.AvatarName);
                string worldName = sender.GetString(Attributes.WorldName);

                //Greet the user via a whisper. Whisper makes use of a session number to target a user
                //Session numbers are an extremely important concept in the SDK and are used to identify
                //users when certain events occur or when sending some command to a specific user.
                sender.Whisper(userSession, "Welcome to {0}, {1}! Enjoy your stay.", worldName, userName);

                //Show that the user was greeted on the console.
                Console.WriteLine("Greeter user {0}.", userName);
            }
            catch (InstanceException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to greet user (Reason: {0}).", Utility.ReturnCodes[ex.ErrorCode]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work!
Here is my specs:

- Microsoft Windows 8.1
- Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows
- mcafee Internet Security (You never know...)

Here is what the project consists of:

- A Visual C# Empty Project
- x86 solution platform(required)

And includes the following files

- A C# Class called MainScript.cs (which houses the code above)
- An AW.Core.dll file in the project's root folder, added as a Reference. (This is the    wrapper)
- An Aw.dll file located in RootFolder\bin\x86\Release\ (This is the C++ DLL used by the wrapper)
- The usual things in a C# Empty Project

those are the only things I have adjusted
The errors I get are:

> Error 3 'AW.Utility' does not contain a definition for 'ReturnCodes'
>   Line 54 Column 81
>
> Error 5 'AW.Utility' does not contain a definition for 'ReturnCodes' Line 66 Column 102
>
> Error 7 'AW.Utility' does not contain a definition for 'ReturnCodes' Line 76 Column 78
>
> Error 9 'AW.Utility' does not contain a definition for 'ReturnCodes' Line 105 Column 82
>
> Error 1 The type name 'Events' does not exist in the type 'AW.Instance' Line 42 Column 59
>
> Error 2 The type or namespace name 'InstanceException' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Line 52 Column 24
>
> Error 4 The type or namespace name 'InstanceException' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Line 64 Column 24
>
> Error 6 The type or namespace name 'InstanceException' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Line 74 Column 20
>
> Error 2 The type or namespace name 'InstanceException' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Line 103 Column 20

You may be wondering where you can get your hands on the .dlls, here is a few links

- The Activeworlds SDK (The C++ .dll) is found here: http://wiki.activeworlds.com/index.php?title=SDK
- The download for the SDK (The C++ .dll) I'm using is here: http://objects.activeworlds.com/downloads/awsdk101.zip
- The source code for the wrapper (The C# .dll) you can find here: `https://github.com/Bloyteg/AW.SDK.Core` (Note, the information may not be all that accurate)
- The download for the C# wrapper you can find here: `https://github.com/Bloyteg/AW.SDK.Core/releases/download/0.3.14.100/AW.Core.zip`

(The reason for the quotes is because I can't post any more links)

Please take a look at this. I'm very new to Visual Studio because I usually code in Unity 3D with MonoDevelopment. I'm an ameteur C# coder so please be patient. This is a not very well documented process and often the developers who work with it are to busy for the likes of me. Plus the other coders use VB.net and C++ rather than C#.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source that you linked to, AW.Utility.ReturnCodes doesn't exist.

Change everywhere that you've written an exception to the console to just write the exception. i.e.

```
Console.WriteLine("Unexpected Error: {0}.", ex);
```

Also, looks like there is no InstanceException class.  Are you sure you're not looking for one of these:
https://github.com/Bloyteg/AW.SDK.Core/tree/master/AW.Core/AW/Exceptions

Lastly, are you missing out some of your code here? The compiler is complaining about a reference to a type that doesn't exist "Events" but I don't see that in your provided code.  My first two comments should clear up the majority of your issues, let me know if you need more help.